# foreach first element add a class

Tags: php

image folder has 3 files

```
<img src='images/AAA_1.jpg'>
<img src='images/AAA_2.jpg'>
<img src='images/AAA_3.jpg'>
<img src='images/BBB_1.jpg'>
<img src='images/BBB_2.jpg'>
<img src='images/BBB_3.jpg'>
<img src='images/CCC_3.jpg'>
```

PHP is

```
    foreach ($carousel as $image) {
        if(strpos($image, 'AAA_') === 0){
          echo "<div class='box'><img src='images/carousel/$image'/></div>";
       }
    }
```

so the output is

```
<div class='box'>
   <img src='images/AAA_1.jpg'>
</div>
<div class='box'>
   <img src='images/AAA_2.jpg'>
</div>
<div class='box'>
   <img src='images/AAA_3.jpg'>
</div>
```

How can I add a `first` class on the fist box, looks like

```
<div class='box first'>
   <img src='images/AAA_1.jpg'>
</div>
<div class='box'>
   <img src='images/AAA_2.jpg'>
</div>
<div class='box'>
   <img src='images/AAA_3.jpg'>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want it just on the first entry of a complete list of files? Or on change of filename group? i.e AAA_3 to BBB_1. And only if there are more than 1 file in the group? just curious.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks! yes you got the point!! I just found I need every group the first one. so if I filter all images AAA_1.jpg, BBB_1.jpg, and CCC_1.jpg need `frist` class inserted

Comment: That makes it 'interesting' :-). The answers provided can be amended to do what you want. I suggest you amend your question to show exactly what you want to be output. That helps us a lot.

Comment: You need to start a new question as you have already accepted the answer and the reward has been given to the person that gave the answer you accepted. You do not have to accept an answer that doesn't do what you want. Although you need to try and ask for what you want. That can be difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the key:

```
foreach ($carousel as $key=>$image) {
    $first = $key == 0 ? ' first' : '';
    if(strpos($image,'AAA_') === 0){

        echo <<<EOD

        <div class='box{$first}'>
           <img src='images/carousel/{$image}.jpg'>
        </div>

EOD;

    }
}
```

Note: I used a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) statement for the echo as I prefer to echo multiple tags of HTML over multiple lines.

Comment: I was going to comment about using 'php alterative syntax' as another approach to multirow html layout in PHP code blocks. Thinking about it, i rather like your use of 'heredoc

Answer (score 1):

Simple: Use a flag.

```
$firstEchoed = FALSE;
foreach ($carousel as $image) {
    if(strpos($image,'AAA_') === 0){
      echo "<div class='box";
      if ( ! $firstEchoed)
        echo " first";

      echo "'><img src='images/carousel/$image'/></div>";
      $firstEchoed = TRUE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean flag, or add count param to **foreach**:

```
foreach ($carousel as $i => $image)
```